# Returning all elements of a JSON array

Tags: jquery, json

I have a form that is posted via AJAX and am trying to display the entire returned array inside a div with the id `results`:

```
var formData = $('#contactform').serialize();

$.ajax({
    type : 'POST', 
    url : 'formprocess.php', 
    data : formData, // our data object
    dataType : 'json', 
    encode : true
}).done(function(data) { 

        $('#results').append(data); // I know this isn't right

});
```

In formprocess.php, I have:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        $data[$key] = $value;
    }

echo json_encode($data);
```

I obviously know how I have it doesn't work. How would I go about taking the entire `data` array and printing the contents on the page so that I can see everything it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#results').append( JSON.stringify(data) );
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
 .done(function(data) { 
    var myarray = JSON.parse(data);

    for (var key in myarray ) {
        if (myarray .hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            $('#results').append('<div>' + myarray [key] + '</div>'); 
        }
    }
 });
```